# How do I duplicate an image selected in a OpenDialog

Tags: c#, image

I have created a C# Windows Forms Application which among other components contains a button. When this button is clicked an OpenFileDialog is opened through which a image file may be selected. I want this image to be duplicated to another folder and have the same name. Specifically to a folder called 'Images' within the Debug folder of my Visual Studio project. Additionally I need this image-copy from its new location to be displayed in a pictureBox on the GUI. This is what I have working so far...

```
private void createNewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Image tempImage;
   string destinationDirectory = @"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\ImageEditorProject\bin\Debug\Images";
   imageDisplayerPictureBox.Controls.Clear();
   OpenFileDialog fileOpener = new OpenFileDialog();
   fileOpener.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png|All Files (*.*)|*.*";

if (fileOpener.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   filePath = fileOpener.FileName;
   //Image must be duplicated to Images folder
   imageDisplayerPictureBox.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(destinationDirectory);            
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this function

```
File.Copy();
```